# How to begin with number one every new day in Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

How to begin with number one for Recordes that will add every new day in Mysql Database .
I need code or method for that.
Thanks

Comment: Check if you have a record for day if no then recordno = 1 if yes then add 1

Comment: Hi .... how to that.... if U give me example

Comment: Tell you what, You try something , if you get into difficulty add what you have tried to the quetsion and someone may help you out.

Comment: Thank U P.Salmon....

Answer (score 0):

You can Fetch Data from Database in Descending order using

`"order by id DESC"` in sql query

Comment: Thanks for replying me... for this I mean... i  need new column to add auto numbering everyday begin from 1 because I need to known a count  of Records eatich single day ..... i looking for PHP code or method in Mysql for that...

Comment: you can schedule the query for that

Comment: Thinks Jagdish Sharma for your replying me and your time... but not work for me

Comment: I think P.Salmon understood what I looking for when he's replying Check if you have a record for day if no then recordno = 1 if yes then add 1 –  .... how is that

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE EVENT reset
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 HOUR
        DO
update T1 
set state=1 
where time < date_sub(now(),interval 24 hour) 
  and (state=0 or state=2) ;
```

it will run in every hour

Comment: 161013001

Where:

16 is Year, 
10 is Month, 
13 is day 
and 001 is auto-increment numbers that reset each days.

Eg.

161012-001
161012-002
161012-002
161013-001
161013-002
161014-001
161014-002
161014-003
161014-004
161014-005
161015-001

Regards

Comment: This what I mean